Sequential processing for Identical request payload, where as parallel processing for non-identical payloads
I have a Kafka consumer written in springboot application, which consumes the payload from Kafka topic called matchupdates, process it and save it to database. Since I am having huge updates receiving for the match, respective payload can be identified using the matchId.
consider following are the payloads which springboot service consumes, where M1,M2 are nothing but the matchId, and respective updates denotes the fields.
M1 -> (update1)  {matchid,name,....}
M1 -> (update2)  {matchid,name,....}
M1 -> (update3)  {matchid,name,....}
M2 -> (update1)  {matchid,name,....}
M2 -> (update2)  {matchid,name,....}
Here my requirement is,** identical payloads should be consumed sequentially only** (i.e. update1,update2, update3 of the matchId M1 should be processed sequentially(i.e. processing, and updates in database, and** if any operation taking longer in execution then rest of the updates should wait in the queue**) whereas, update1 of M1 and update2 of M2 can be processed parallelly.
Can I achieve this using service executors or any other way in Java through which I can processes identical payloads sequentially only and if required they need to be wait in Queue until ahead updates are not processing.
I tried using threadpool executor with the Queue, but every time it is assigning to different thread available in the pool, which causes to payloads getting executed parallelly with the identical MatchId.

In Java we have BlockingQueue https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html which can help you. Create as many Blocking Queues as the number of M1, M2, ... Suppose we know it. If not we should think how to reuse our queues. When message from topic consumed read its matchid and dispatch the message to corresponding queue. Dispatcher executed in one thread and process messages sequentially. It works fast because putting message and read message from queue don't take much time. The main time is spent by processing messages and database interaction. So we create the same number of thread as many queues we have. You might use fixed thread pool or create threads as new Thread, the important thing is that each thread must serve it's own queue. In such way it will process each messages with the same matchid sequentially but writing to the database will be in parallel

Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() for each "matchId" should work but then executor will keep on consuming the resources and will have idle threads waiting for that matchid forever since we can't shutdown accross multiple requests.We want something like CachedThreadPool which terminates the thread if idle for more than "keepAlive" time.Hence using customized ThreadPoolExecutor using combination of both.
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, ExecutorService> taskMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //list of updates
        //ArrayList<String> listOfUpdates = new ArrayList<>();
        
        String matchId = "M1";
        ExecutorService executor = taskMap.computeIfAbsent(matchId, k -> createSingleTaskExecutor());
        executor.submit(Scratch::dbSaveTask);
        executor.submit(Scratch::dbSaveTask);
        System.out.println("Main ended");
        executor.submit(Scratch::dbSaveTask);

   }

    public static ExecutorService createSingleTaskExecutor() {
        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 1, 5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
    }

    private static void dbSaveTask() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Task started");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            System.out.println("Task ended");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

The program terminates after "keepAlive" time since no active threads.(Try to make keepAlive time close to maximum overlap of same matchId).
The only problem still pending is cleanup of map entries which could be taken care by scheduled service/job at end of day.
